# Trying to teleport mobs to a random location around a player

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I can't get the location setup correctly. I've tried a few ways and what I came to now I felt was right but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
package nathaniel.newplugin.eventlistener;



import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerDropItemEvent;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffect;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffectType;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class PlayerDrop implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void PlayerDropItemEvent(PlayerDropItemEvent e) {
        List<EntityType> list = Arrays.asList(EntityType.CREEPER, EntityType.WITHER, EntityType.ALLAY, EntityType.AXOLOTL, EntityType.BAT, EntityType.BEE, EntityType.BLAZE, EntityType.CAT, EntityType.CAVE_SPIDER, EntityType.CHICKEN, EntityType.COD, EntityType.COW, EntityType.DOLPHIN, EntityType.DONKEY, EntityType.DROWNED, EntityType.ELDER_GUARDIAN, EntityType.ENDERMAN, EntityType.ENDERMITE, EntityType.EVOKER, EntityType.FOX, EntityType.FROG, EntityType.GHAST, EntityType.GIANT, EntityType.GOAT, EntityType.GUARDIAN, EntityType.HOGLIN, EntityType.HORSE, EntityType.HUSK, EntityType.ILLUSIONER, EntityType.IRON_GOLEM, EntityType.LIGHTNING, EntityType.LLAMA, EntityType.MAGMA_CUBE, EntityType.MULE, EntityType.MUSHROOM_COW, EntityType.OCELOT, EntityType.PANDA, EntityType.PARROT, EntityType.PHANTOM, EntityType.PIG, EntityType.PIGLIN, EntityType.PIGLIN_BRUTE, EntityType.PILLAGER, EntityType.POLAR_BEAR, EntityType.PRIMED_TNT, EntityType.PUFFERFISH, EntityType.RABBIT, EntityType.RAVAGER, EntityType.SALMON, EntityType.SHEEP, EntityType.SHULKER, EntityType.SILVERFISH, EntityType.SLIME, EntityType.SPIDER, EntityType.SQUID, EntityType.STRAY, EntityType.STRIDER, EntityType.TADPOLE, EntityType.TROPICAL_FISH, EntityType.TURTLE, EntityType.VEX, EntityType.VILLAGER, EntityType.VINDICATOR, EntityType.WARDEN, EntityType.WITCH, EntityType.WITHER_SKELETON, EntityType.WOLF, EntityType.ZOGLIN, EntityType.ZOMBIE);
        Random random = new Random();
        Player player = e.getPlayer();
        int x = random.nextInt(10);
        int y = random.nextInt(2);
        int z = random.nextInt(10);
        Location randomLocation = new Location(player.getWorld(),x,y,z);
        player.getWorld().spawnEntity(player.getLocation(randomLocation), list.get(random.nextInt(list.size())));
        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.SPEED, 50, 1));



    }
}
```

I expected it to teleport a random location around the bound around the player.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the random offset you calculate to the position of the player.

The location you calculate is something like this

```
player.getLocation().add(x,y,z)
```

And actually if I understood right your problem you should reduce your x,y and z by half the offset so I can spawn all around the player.
For example:

```
x = random.nextInt(10) - 5;
```